# Windows not see ubuntu files

Tags: 14.04

I had ubuntu 14.04 in my laptop but my laptop crashed due to gpu error. So i took off my hdd because i have important files there.

I connect via usb with box but my windows couldnot recognize files. So , from here
http://www.howtogeek.com/112888/3-ways-to-access-your-linux-partitions-from-windows/

i downloaded those 3 programs but those only showed the name of folders, not inside. Also not every folder. They were Just like recovery programs when we try to recover data from hdd which we formatted for example.

Is not there any better ways to do this? Maybe putting this hdd to my desktop and wait it to recognize it as a os to boot?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to use a bootable Ubuntu LiveDVD or bootable Ubuntu LiveUSB and boot to that ..

Install the laptop's HD into your PC (actually if you have it hooked up through USB it still should work). Boot to the USB/DVD and choose the try option. You will be able to access both your windows drives and the linux ones so you should be able to use the LiveCD/DVD to copy the important files

Answer (score 1):

Use Linux Reader or Ext2Fsd; I personally prefer the former. They're completely free. You should be able to browse the files then from your Windows OS. Or, as the others suggested, use a live DVD or live USB.

Answer (score 0):

Windows can't see Ubuntu files due to ReiserFS partition, so you have to install a third software that recognize ReiserFS partition on Windows or just boot on Ubuntu USB/LIVE CD and read the old partition.